# Flash Loaded Movie Clip Problem

Tags: flash

If anyone feels this question is inapropriate please remove it or notify me and I will.

Im having trouble figuring out this one, Im loading several movieclips into one. One movieclip as the base of the website and the others as individual pages. My problem is that now 3 of those movie clips when loaded appear to have been put off by a pixel or two which makes the text all blurry (pixel font).

I've confirmed that my "container" mc is at x0.0 and y0.0 and that all of the elements in the loaded movieclip are at precise numbers like: 192.0 34.0 not 123.5 or 34.6.

Suggestions are most welcomed ;)

EDIT: I've tried swapping the loaded MC for another one which displays fine and it did, so the problem must be within the loaded swf itself. Since by playing the loaded swf (the one who gets blurry) alone all appears fine and all positions are at .0 I cant really figure out whats going on.

UPDATE: I tried exporting for flash player 7 and it solved the issue any other version above will not work, can anyone provide insight on why this is happening?

Comment: Is the container mc a child of the root stage?

Comment: I assume that if you just open the loaded swf's (so not loading them into another), they look fine?

Comment: @Lieven Cardoen Just opening the loaded swf it looks good. But loaded it does not, altough if I load a diferent one to that spot it looks good, so my bets are that the proble is the loaded swf not the "container"

Comment: Also Im not to sure what you mean with "Is the container mc a child of the root stage?" the "container" is placed on a swf wich has buttons to load into the container the others swf.

Comment: I cant quite understand why all of the sudden if I export in flash 7 they just work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to set your mc to not scale as well as be TL aligned? do a trace to make sure that they're sitting on a pixel relative to the stage:

```
trace(root.stage.container.x) //as3 or
trace(_root.container._x) //as2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with loading a swf that contains a png into a container swf.  The loaded swf looked like it was scaling the png, but opening the swf outside the container looked fine.  So I tried setting

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; // in as3

in the container and that fixed it.